# common.apiexception.c: Not on the main thread

Tags: android, google-maps

I get this error when i try to add a marker to a GoogleMaps Map:

```
   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.c: Not on the main thread
```

what can i do to fix this?
-this is the class that spawns the marker:

```
   public class MobSpawner {
public LatLng posPlayer=new LatLng(1,1);
Randomizzatore valori=new Randomizzatore();


public void setPosPlayer(LatLng posPlayer) {
    this.posPlayer = posPlayer;
}
public void spawna(){
    Marker mPosMostro;
    LatLng posMostro=new LatLng(valori.randomCoord(posPlayer.latitude),valori.randomCoord(posPlayer.longitude));
    mPosMostro = MapsActivity.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posMostro).title("mostroo"));
}}
```

Comment: Please share code of your `MapsActivity`. Seems you should call `MapsActivity.this.mMap` instead of `MapsActivity.mMap`.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i foud out what was the problem,the kind of timer i was using was not capable of updating the view.